# connection of jio wifi in Android 5.1 version

Tags: wi-fi

Recently my college had opened jio WiFi it was open WiFi connection my phone Micromax q346 model Android 5.1version can not connected how I connect to WiFi on my phone small version phones are supported to WiFi but not please help me how I connect to it

Comment: Details please - for example, define "can not connect" with what errors pop up or a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites recommend to restart the router device, and sometime it works.
Instead of every time restart the router to solve the Wi-Fi problem, it worked for me:

Inside the router configuration (e.g., accessing the IP 192.168.0.1), change the "Group key update" value from 0 to 30 seconds, under the "Wireless > Security" configuration, right below the WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK item.

Router: TP-LINK TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND.